# MATLAB remove same numbers from an array

Tags: matlab, vectorization

```
%Remove duplicated numbers from A to get B
A=[1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5];
B=[1 2 3 4 5];
```

What is a simple way (without a loop is possible) to create B from A (i.e. remove same numbers from array A)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MATLAB builtin command `unique` allows you to extract all unique values from an array:

```
A=[1 1 1 2 2 3 4 4 5];
B=unique(A);
B=[1 2 3 4 5];
```

see: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html

Answer (score 0):

`B = unique(A)`

this should work :)

EDIT:

From [`unique()` documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html),

> C = unique(A) returns the same data as in A, but with no repetitions.
>
> - If A is a numeric array, logical array, character array, categorical array, datetime array, duration array, or a cell array of
>     strings, then unique returns the unique values in A. The values of C
>     are in sorted order.
> - If A is a table, then unique returns the unique rows in A. The rows of table C are in sorted order.

Comment: This is much better.